# Haunt #43 The Star Sickness very confused

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

We were playing this haunt tonight and it was really confusing so hopefully someone can clear up some questions for me I don't really get how this scenario works.

Why after each round are we rolling for damage? I can understand the infected people are rolling, but why everyone? The way I see it, if you aren't infected (yet) than why are you rolling for what appears to be random damage? If you have been infected I can see why you would roll for this.

What is the point of the traitor trying to infect people? This I can't wrap my head around. It doesn't really feel like a traitor at all, just the carrier who is trying to infect everyone but for what purpose? I know that the tokens are chosen randomly. For example, the person infecting is player A and player B takes the infect token. OK...now what? Player B is now a 'traitor' but this doesn't really seem to matter. Is Player B now trying to infect player C and player D? But again...what for? Everyone rolls for damage every turn and its only a matter of time before everyone dies or becomes an alien anyway.

I just really don't get how the traitor(s) work in this game. If player B gives it to player C and then on to player D, now everyone has become a traitor and the game is over? Because now we are all traitors and are on the same team? I just don't get this at all. I understand that if you are infected and you die, you become an alien. But what is the point of the alien? To slow down the last remaining non-infected person?

Hopefully someone out there can help me better understand this.

Answer (score 3):

### Rolling damage each round

The opening flavour text describes three stages of infection, the first of which states:

> it feels like a particularly virulent fever, as your immune system fights against it...

And then in the section under **The Haunt Revealer Must Do This...**:

> the alien disease battles everyone's immune system.

This means that every one of the investigators is already at stage one of the infection. You are not becoming infected by receiving the number 1 monster token, you are just progressing to stage two.

### The traitor and infection

Don't think of the infection spread mechanic as a part of the traitors abilities/effects or a traitorous thing to do - this mechanic is not really related to the traitor at all since everyone has to do this - it is just the way the status of being a traitor spreads.

As you say this mechanic is just reflecting that they are a carrier spreading the development of stage two infection. There is no real malicious intent in this since it is meant to be a 50% random chance of passing on the infection.

However the introduction does also say that

> In the second stage, the spores take over the host's mind.

The traitors are more than welcome to subtly sabotage the game for the survivors, since the development of the Serum is a bad thing for them.

They may be able to slow down or prevent the other survivors from getting the Serum with subtle actions: redirecting or planting suspicion on other players, taking longer to get somewhere, using/not using an item that would hinder/help the cause, ensuring they do/don't offer strategic tips or reminders that would hinder/help the search for a cure etc.

### The point of the aliens

The aliens are indicators that a survivor has progressed to the third stage, and is a visible display of their infection. Generally speaking they will likely be tougher than your investigator, especially since they are immune to the ongoing damage from stage one and have fairly good stats - the only real downside is that they can't spread the infection since they are no longer explorers.

This stage could potentially be considered the next logical step towards a win when you are a traitor after having swapped your infection tokens a couple of times, since it lets you be more open about your actions against the other players, and lets you more freely either kill survivors or force other traitors to transform.

It becomes even more important to be an alien if one or more survivors have been injected with the Serum.

After being treated with the Serum survivors are immune to the per round damage and can no longer trade infection tokens. Being at stage three means you can actively pursue and attack cured survivors, leaving other potential traitors to stay hidden and affect things more subtly, and even if all you do is sacrifice yourself in doing so, you can also prevent or at least delay someone with the Serum from injecting other traitors.

Comment: Those links are for the revised first edition books, which is different than the second edition books. The linked version say "revised" because they do fix a few rules and wordings, but they are still the original 1st edition scenarios. "The Star Sickness" is only in the second edition, for which the rules are not available online.

Comment: Hmm. My bad, I had assumed (obviously incorrectly) that mine was 1st ed, probably since I didn't hear about there being a 2nd ed until I had my copy for over a year. I'll remove the offending part based on my misinformation.